# How to convert an Image from IWICBitmap to byte-array?

Tags: c++, windows, image, arrays

I have an image in IWICBitmap object on windows platform. Now I need to store that image into a byte array. I was trying with `CopyPixels` method, but it is giving me following error:

`Insufficient buffer passed.`

Comment: Well...show us how you call CopyPixel and how you determine buffer size (in general it should be width*height*bytes per pixel, 4 if ARGB).

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Details of Image are as flows. Width 1080 pixels, height 1920 pixels and bit depth is 24. Is bit depth is same as bytes per pixel? Its a JPEG image.